# directive is not a known element in test

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

The structure is like this... it should become a npm module...

```
.
./angular.json
./karma.conf.js
./package.json
./tsconfig.json
./demo
./demo/index.html
./demo/main.ts
./demo/test.ts
./demo/tsconfig.app.json
./demo/tsconfig.spec.json
./demo/app
./demo/app.component.html
./demo/app.component.ts
./demo/app.component.spec.ts
./demo/app.module.ts
```

Then there is the lib code

```
./lib/index.ts
./lib/src/libname.module.ts
./lib/src/libname/libname.component.html
./lib/src/libname/libname.component.ts
```

The component works with `ng serve`.

If I run my tests with `ng test` I see Template parse errors for `directivename is not a known element`.

I've tried adding the lib-files to the files array in tsconfig.spec.json.
No success.

The only thing **working** is, that I import **all the Components from the lib and all Components used by my lib** in the app.component.spec.ts and add them to the TestBed-declarations.

But that is not possible that I would have to add all the components by myself like this to a test.

I must miss something. Do you know what?

Comment: Without a [mcve] of the component and test in question, it's really hard to guess.

Comment: Try to reproduce your test by adding a demo, you can clone this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-c25ezq?file=app/app.component.spec.ts

Comment: @HDJEMAI there is a demo and the demo works like I've written. It is just that in test I've to declare all internal components by myself. That shouldn't be the case when there are components in components in components. You don't know what components are used in the internal components. In your link this would be, when you use in the NavBarComponent a NavBarChildComponent. Then you would have to put the NavBarChildComponent also to the Testbed declarations.

Comment: I've added it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-vnfmhx?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

Answer (score 1):

I've found it ;-)

Instead of

```
// refine the test module by declaring the test component
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [NavBarComponent, NavBarChildComponent],
  providers: [
    {provide: Location, useValue: location}
    ]
});
```

I've to use

```
// refine the test module by declaring the test component
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [NavBarModule],
  providers: [
    {provide: Location, useValue: location}
    ]
});
```